Property setter cannot be protected when getter is internal - why?
Why is this a bug?
internal class VisualControl : IDisposable
{
    internal int Property { get; protected set; } = 4;
}

Compiler gives Compiler error CS0273.

The accessibility modifier of the 'VisualControl.Property.set' accessor must be more restrictive than the property or indexer 'VisualControl.Property' (CS0273)

It basically works with public but not with internal. Why?

This code works fine for me.

No repro. Compiles fine for me in C# for .NET 8

I use .NET 8 too

Maybe it inherits from a base class or implements an interface? Show the complete code please.

It's impossible for a protected set; to cause CS0273 with a public property because CS0273 requires set to have a less restrictive accessor than the property, but nothing is less-restrictive than public. So the OP is hiding something...

@noonespecial I can repro it with internal but not public. Please show us a repro with public.

I edited the message, now you can find the image with prove :)

@noonespecial Your edit only shows an internal property, not a public property which your question-title claims. - unless you mean you did internal int Prop { get; public set; }?

No, no, @Dai, you closed the question but the link you pasted does not give the answer.  I would like to have be available publicly (or internal) for read while write only for the class as well as for inheritance

@noonespecial "I would like to have be available publicly (or internal) for read while write only for the class as well as for inheritanc" then do public int Prop { get; protected set; }

Protected is more accessible than internal, because it's available outside the assembly. If you declare your prop as internal you have to make your set more restricted than that if youre applying a modifier to it

I see that the goal is still to close the question as quickly as possible rather than to answer it. Protected is more restrictive than internal. Therefore, there is no correct answer." https://dotnetfiddle.net/KqxffL

Exactly. Thank you for pointing this out. I already noticed this asking few other questions related to C#. I am new to the topic so obviously I have many questions, but community rather aims to close the question to forbid others form helping. Surprisingly the "closers" are from M$... Does C# really suck so much that they need to do this? The very same happens on other M$ forums. It is definitely a time for stack overflow to take a carefool look at this behavior.
